# Hosting LAMP on SD-card in RPi now - would like to move whole database and website to External USB 3.0 SSD

Tags: pi-4, web-server, data-transfer, usb3

.I am hosting this [website](https://vuh.dk) on the RPi 4 - 4GB Ram model.

I'm guessing the google [PageSpeed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=da) ranking score is kinda ok right now (it ranges in the middel with a score of 56) - try and test it yourself if you want too, and see if your get the same score (it's just a temp. landing page with text, no photos and one plugin to Facebook.

But I want more speed, I wanna be able to upload large files to my webpage quickly and I think USB 3.0 + External SSD with Exts4 on it will do the trick nicely.

So:

Thewebpage files + database does not need to MOVED exactly - it's a test-site, and I will gladly delete evrything that has to do with LAMP on the Pi, and start from a fresh all over to install things the right way.

I am LOST in words for what I should search for on Google - I get loads of diffrent results when searching on "hosting usb 3.0 ssd on rpi 4". Here is a picture of ht e test setup, just for fun: [image]

So how can Install a LAMP on my external USB disk instead of the 16 GB SD-card wichc is much slow in comparison and make sure everything is set up correctly on not just "works" as good as before..?

NB: I even found a used Dell Server SSD with Random Sector (I think it's called) write speeds of 220 GigaBYTE pr. second... At least that's what crystalDisk/Mark said it had.. Could this be awesome in terms of web page speed?

Comment: Should I move this to another Stackoverflow board about linux in general or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question - it's even official documentation. Right here is a guide of moving all data from SD-card to USB-device and then boot the boot files from SD bot all other files will be run from the SSD USB device.

The link to the guide (work-around): [https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1230182&fbclid=IwAR3idP38EqveSMxbark8R7mqxSEm6u0Js7Ijt1dr0aGBYn1rLK9NkhsTgm8#p1230182][1]

So the real answer is not to run just LAMP on the SSD but the whole Raspian OS :) Thanks to all that helped this far.

Answer (score 3):

> I want more speed, I wanna be able to upload large files to my webpage
> quickly and I think USB 3.0 + External SSD with Exts4 on it will do
> the trick nicely.

Mount your external drive to `apache2` web files path. At first, find out what's the name of your drive on `/dev`:

```
cat /proc/partitions | grep sd
```

You might see something like this:

```
   8        0   30031250 sda
   8        1   30030226 sda1
```

Which the drive name is `sda`. So, mount this drive to the web files path:

```
sudo mount -o defaults /dev/sda /var/www/mysite
```

Changing permissions of your folder to allow `www-data` (apache2) to write:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mysite
```

In addition, you may reach a better speed if you install the whole `apache2` package on your external drive but I'm not sure and have not done something like that.

---

> I even found a used Dell Server SSD with Random Sector (I think it's
> called) write speeds of 220 GigaBYTE pr. second... At least that's
> what crystalDisk/Mark said it had.. Could this be awesome in terms of
> web page speed?

It's not related to "Raspberry Pi" hence please ask these questions in the appropriate SE site.

Comment: Thank you! Is it really that easy to do? Wow! I will set this up and try it in a matter of minutes, at most 1 hour, and then get back to you with some results.

And I don't even have to reinstall LAMP... :D Or set it up diferently either or am I wrong?

Comment: @ITBlacksmith No, you don't need to reinstall packages but I added a new part to the answer "In addition, ...". Alright, good luck.

Comment: YE, I just saw that. I might wanna google how to solve that first or after I move the server files to the exSSD?

Comment: @ITBlacksmith Yes, it's not complicated. Did you accomplish this project?

Comment: The first solution you posted worked... not quite... I followed your instructions, no errors. But check my website now: denied access - a persmissions problem?

There is no SSD set up in the Pi right now, maybe that's why,.... How do I revert the things I did?

Comment: On tuesdag next week I will setup the SSD-drive with a Samsung EVO 850 SSD in try that instead (was'nt satisfied with the Dell one). Then I will give it a try again with USB 3.0 hosting.

Comment: You can run `sudo umount /dev/sda`. You need to add your files to `/var/www/`. I mean, `/var/www/` => `https://vuh.dk/` AND `/var/www/mysite` => `https://vuh.dk/mysite` to figure it out.

Comment: Thx man, that did the trick. All up and running on SD-card again. As said in earlier comment I will continue this project on tuesday next week.